# Updating an sql xml field which has xmlnamespaces

Tags: sql, xml

I have an xml string which I can read the value of the ID out with

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES
       ('http://collaborate.com/svn/capabilities/tdp/ManageNetworkAndServiceDiagnosticsV4/' AS P, 
'https://collaborate.com/svn/edm/tdp/Test' as p2)
Select @id = feed.xx.value('.','VARCHAR(50)')  
From   @smxml.nodes('/p:initiateTest/p2:Test/p2:id') feed(xx)
```

This sets the @ID variable, which I amend, and then I want to place it back into the table.
I have tried

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES
('http://collaborate.com/svn/capabilities/tdp/ManageNetworkAndServiceDiagnosticsV4/' AS p, 
'https://collaborate.com/svn/edm/tdp/Test' as p2)
UPDATE CT_GTCS_Temp_XML
SET xmlStartString.modify('replace value of (/p:initiateTest/p2:Test/p2:id with @New_Id)')
```

BUt I get an error of 
XQuery [CT_GTCS_Temp_XML.xmlStartString.modify()]: ")" was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggested, you didn't put the closing bracket in correct place. Put it right after the XQuery, not after `with` clause :

```
.....
SET xmlStartString.modify('replace value of 
                                (/p:initiateTest/p2:Test/p2:id/text())[1] 
                           with sql:variable("@New_Id")')
```

Comment: XQuery [CT_GTCS_Temp_XML.xmlStartString.modify()]: The target of 'replace value of' must be a non-metadata attribute or an element with simple typed content, found 'element(p2{https://collaborate.bt.com/svn/edm/tdp/Test}:id,xdt:untyped) ?'

Comment: updated my answer, trailing `/text()` added to the XQuery. We want to replace value of the node, not the node it self.